# Live and work in USA but need to move back to Aus - any insight from others regarding continuing employment? (Dual USA/AUS citizenship)

Tags: usa, australia, freelance, foreign-employment

So here's my situation: I currently live and work in the USA, but  I've been working remotely since march and recently told my employer I need to move back to Aus, and that I was hoping I could keep my job and be fully remote.

Now, the company I work for isn't exactly fast-moving or up with the times. They've so far made it sound like it's really difficult and I may not be able to keep my job.

I have zero confidence in our HR person to do any real research into this, so I kind of need to figure it out on my own, but I haven't been able to find much online that's up to date.

Does anyone have experience with this? If I can make it as simple as possible for my employer I'm way more likely to keep my job. It's not exactly high paying but I'd prefer to keep it than not right now.

I'm happy to get an ABN and deal with whatever I need to with the ATO/IRS but considering my financial situation I don't really have the option of going to an accountant right now.

Comment: It might help you get better answers if you provided some more background. What kind of obstacles to this plan is your employer putting up? What kind of work is it? Do they have other non US-based employees working remotely? To what extent would the time difference affect your work and ability to interact with your colleagues/support team back in the US? What kind of a business case to back up your request did you present to your employer? I suspect even large employers might not react positively to such a request without a strong case demonstrating the benefit to them, not just you

Comment: They're not putting up any specific obstacles that I know of, but they're very slow to get things done in general.

It's digital marketing/ecommerce work. We're an extremely small team with one person located in another country already, but I don't know if they're on a contract or retainer.

The time difference is minimal and considering that it's basically my boss and me keeping things running in our department there's a strong case for keeping me on. I think their main concern is tax/labor laws in Australia, but I wouldn't be surprised if someone higher up just says "too hard, move on".